# Creating a jar file from a source code for minecraft

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, minecraft

I'm trying to create a Java plugin for Minecraft, from an open source code. I'm really a beginner in this field, this is also my first thread here.
My question is :
How do I create this Java file, from the source code? I have Eclipse, but I don't really know what to do!
Can someone please explain me how to do it? Or even if you can give me a tutorial, it would be really helpful!

Here's the Source Code :
https://github.com/Gregory1346/NavyCraft-Reloaded/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta-1

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can try using `mvn package` but you need to install maven for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given project is a maven project. I know it thanks to the `pom.xml` file. You can take a look [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html) about how to config maven project.

1. Import this project (with the link of the github project, not the 3.0.0 tag) in eclipse
2. Right click on project
3. In "Run as" section, use `Maven install`. There is also other options to update your project or dependencies.

It will generate jar in `target` folder.

If it failed, you should check for outdated maven dependencies, or ask the author that gave some way to [contact him](https://github.com/Gregory1346/NavyCraft-Reloaded#contact-info) on the github page

Comment: I tried to do what you've said but I've stopped at your point 3, since I can't see the "install" button

Comment: Yes sorry, it's in "Run as" section. I just edit my answer